# Differences between Excel 2003 and 2007 from a VSTO perspective

Tags: .net, excel, vsto

What are some of the major differences to be aware of when developing Addins or Document level customizations for excel 2003/2007?

Answer (score 1):

A couple items:

VSTO 2SE - can be used for both Excel 2003 and Excel 2007 addins.  (requires code-access security on installation)

VSTO 3 - can only be used for Excel 2007 add-ins. (Does not require code-access security)

Excel 2003 - can install add-in for all users or per-user.

Excel 2007 - Can only install add-in per/user.

Answer (score 0):

FYI.  The blog article mentioned above is not accurate in document level customizations.  Perhaps at the time it was, but it is no longer accurate.

Excel 2007 Document Level Customizations are fully supported in Visual Studio 2008 however they utilize Visual Studio Tools For Office 2007 (aka VSTO 3.0).